# Proper way to check if an unbound control has a value

Tags: ms-access, vba

Simple scenario: a form and one text box (unbound), `Text1`.

```
If "" <> Text1 Then
    MsgBox "Not Empty"
End If
```

The above code works. The expression `""<> Text1` evaluates to True if the text box contain characters.

The opposite doesn't work, regardless of the text box is empty or not:

```
If "" = Text1 Then  ' or alternatively, False = ("" <> Text1)
     MsgBox "Empty!"
End If
```

Can you clarify this issue?

Comment: You really should specify the parent of the control you're looking at, i.e., Me!Text1. It makes for more readable code and avoids compilation errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The textbox is usually null if it does not contain anything, this is not the same as a zero length string (""). It can often be best to use:

```
If Trim(Text1 & "") = vbNullString
   'Empty
```

This will be true if the textbox contains spaces, a zero length string or null.

Comment: @Remou, I like the `Text1 & ""` part. It's a smart way to *avoid* assignments to null values. Thanks.

Comment: Why not "Me!Text & vbNullString = vbNullString"? Trim() serves no purpose, except to treat a textbox with one or more spaces as equivalent to a Null textbox. While an unbound textbox can't contain multiple spaces, a bound textbox *may* contain them (though they won't survive an edit in a form control).

Comment: I feel that vbNullString is not a particularly good name for a constant that is a zero length string, so I thought that the two forms would make it clearer.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, I've got a small function that I find useful for checking that sort of thing when dealing with various variable types and I just want to know whether it's *blank*.

```
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
' True if the argument is Nothing, Null, Empty, Missing or an empty string.   '
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
Public Function IsBlank(arg As Variant) As Boolean
    Select Case VarType(arg)
        Case vbEmpty
            IsBlank = True
        Case vbNull
            IsBlank = True
        Case vbString
            IsBlank = (arg = vbNullString)
        Case vbObject
            IsBlank = (arg Is Nothing)
        Case Else
            IsBlank = IsMissing(arg)
        End Select
End Function
```

Just [Made a blog post](http://blog.nkadesign.com/2009/access-checking-blank-variables/) today about it too.

Comment: your routine will come in handy. Very good answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I always use the [function Nz (variable, valueIfNull)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa172237%28office.11%29.aspx) to check those kind of things. For example:

```
 if (Len(Nz(Me.txt1, "")) > 0) then
        'Me.txt1 does not contain a value
 end if
```

Or if I want to save a textbox's value to a recordset:

```
rst!Name = Nz(Me.txtName, "No name given")
```

Comment: Thanks Markus. I didn't know that function.