# If value is nothing, do something

Tags: ms-access, vba

I use a report in MS Access which displays records out of a database based on dates (given by the user).

I seem to having some trouble using my If Else statement when the Report is loading. I have one row in the database named `BDatGift90`. Sometimes, this value may be empty for a record. In that case, I want to use the If Else statement.

My If Else statement is:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    If IsNull(BDatGift90.Value) Then
        Me.GBedrag10.Visible = True
    Else
        Me.GBedrag.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The report is not loading at all. The text boxes `GBedrag` and `GBedrag10` are not visible and I would like to use my If Else statement to decide what text box has to be visible.

Can I use some error reporting somewhere or is my if else wrong? I could use some explanation from somebody.

Comment: you might need to use the Detail_Format event, try it out. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check the `BDatGift90` while the report is opening. But is `BDatGift90` one column in the recordsource of the record? If yes, which row of the recordsource is being checked by your if else statement? I'm asking because `Report_Open()` is called only once. In contrast, an event like `GroupHeader1_Format()`is called several times, and the values are stepping forward through the recordsource each time.

So, one approach is to clarify the life cycle of `BDatGift90`. Another approach is to set a breakpoint and to inspect `BDatGif90` (VBE > Debug > Add Watch...). Is it `null`, is it `empty`, `nothing` or `""`?

Here is an interesting check for zero-length string in textboxes: [Proper way to check if an unbound control has a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392917/proper-way-to-check-if-an-unbound-control-has-a-value)

And here are more hints about `isEmpty()`, `isNothing()` etc. http://allenbrowne.com/vba-NothingEmpty.html

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: This is a very interesting answer. I cannot vote your answer up yet (Need 15 reputation). It is indeed in a Groupheader format. However, It seem like it does not check if `BDatGift90` is empty or not. It looks like there is no loop.

Comment: Thx for the feedback :-) Try to clarify the process and the surroundings. 1) How many rows are in the report's `RecordSource`, if you open it as a table view? 2) Then, how many rows are presented in the report? Do those numbers 1) and 2) match? 3) If you open the report's `RecordSource` in table view, what do you see in the column `BDatGift90`? Is it what you expect? 4) Are you sure the `BDatGift90` field really has a `ControlSource` set? Does it match to the `RecordSource` table view? etc. Something is sticked together the wrong way. You'll find it :-)

Comment: I am confused. Is there a easy way? Can I over wise just do a If Else in the query?

Comment: In Access Queries, you can use `IIF(condition;if;else)`. It has also an equivalent in the visual query designer. Maybe the query gives you some new insight, but it might happen that the problem is just moved into another corner.

Comment: I solved it using `IsNull(DLookup`. I want to thank you for your kind support and your great help.

Comment: Thanks, that's very kind. Glad I could help and it is now running on your side.

Answer (score 0):

Corresponding to your question, try this:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    If BDatGift90.Value Is Nothing Then
        Me.GBedrag10.Visible = True
    Else
        Me.GBedrag.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, that did not solve it. It seems that it does not loop trough all the records. Both the labels stays hidden.